# Single checkbox check for multiple forms

Tags: jquery, forms, input, checkbox

I have few forms inside one page with different values and the number of these forms will most probably increase during time. Now what I wont is to don't allow users to submit any of those forms until they select a checkbox name="terms" which is appearing only one and it's not placed inside any of those forms. Possible or I will have to place it inside every single form?

```
<input type="checkbox" name="terms" /> Agree to terms and conditions.

<form action="./action/studentMentorSignup.php" method="post" name="studentsForm">
<input type="hidden" value="145" name="mentorID" />
<button class="btn btn-warning" type="submit" name="submitRequest"><i class="icon-check"></i></button>
<a href="#myModal10" role="button" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-info"><i class="icon-info-sign"></i></a>
</form>

<form action="./action/studentMentorSignup.php" method="post" name="studentsForm">
<input type="hidden" value="244" name="mentorID" />
<button class="btn btn-warning" type="submit" name="submitRequest"><i class="icon-check"></i></button>
<a href="#myModal11" role="button" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-info"><i class="icon-info-sign"></i></a>
</form>

<form action="./action/studentMentorSignup.php" method="post" name="studentsForm">
<input type="hidden" value="477" name="mentorID" />
<button class="btn btn-warning" type="submit" name="submitRequest"><i class="icon-check"></i></button>
<a href="#myModal11" role="button" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-info"><i class="icon-info-sign"></i></a>
</form>
```

......

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input type="checkbox" id="terms"> Agree to terms and conditions.
```

Javascript:

```
 $(".forms").submit(function(e){
       if(!$("#terms").is(":checked")){
            //alert('You need to accept terms');
            e.preventDefault();
       }
    });
```

Put a `forms` class to your forms like `<form class="forms"`

Comment: Didn't notice the jQuery tag! =) nice answer +1

Answer (score 1):

Give the checkbox an `ID` so you can target it directly, and test it's checked conditions as a boolean:

```
<label for="terms">Agree to terms and conditions.</label>
<input id="agreefirst" type="checkbox" name="terms" /> 

<script>
     var isChecked = document.getElementById('agreefirst').checked;
     if ( isChecked ) 
         //Code..
</script>
```

This won't have to be in a `<form>` tag, and it can still stay stray from the rest.

Then once you're submitting one of the other forms, you can still test for it,

```
<script>
     function validate( event ) {
         if ( !document.getElementById('agreefirst').checked ) {
              event.preventDefault();
              return false;
         }
     }
</script>

<form action="./action/studentMentorSignup.php" 
      onsubmit="validate( event )" 
      method="post" 
      name="studentsForm">
```